# Sqlite Class Property from JOIN Statement

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, xamarin

I have a class model for Items which contains properties such as ItemId, ItemCategoryId, Desc, Price, etc. I also have a class model for ItemCategories which contains properties such as ItemCategoryId and Name.

The issue that I have run into is I have a page that displays Items with the name of the ItemCategory included, therefore, I do a JOIN statement to return desired columns from the sqlite database. However, to bind my ListView to the Items model and display the Name property from the query results I need to include the Name property in the Items class model.

The Items table in the database does not include a Name field but the Items class model does (because I need it to store the results from the query). This means when I try to insert a new record into the Items table using InsertAsync(item) I get an error saying the table doesn't contain a field called 'Name.'

If I add the [Ignore] tag to Name in the class model it just doesn't show up in my listview.

I feel that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here but I'm new to Xamarin and this way of doing things so how can I get around this issue?

Comment: try making it a read only property (remove the set;)

Comment: Make it read only in the database? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: make the property in your model read only - remove the setter

Comment: On closer inspection, this worked for the insert but now it isn't displaying the Name property. When I debug it's just saying the Name property is Null for each Item.

Comment: you could use SQLite.NET Extensions to setup a FK relation.  Or you could use one model that has the Name property for reads and another that does not for inserts and updates.

Comment: Yeah the latter has been my work around, I was just hoping there was a less messy way to go about it =/

Comment: A FK is probably the "right" solution for this

Comment: You can write your solutions in the answer and mark it which will help more people with same problem:).